# jquery Сложение и вычитание текстовых полей при условии

Tags: html, jquery

Добрый день подскажите как осуществить сложение и вычитание полей по условиям основываясь на Дату

**HTML**

```
<input id="dateInput" name="dateInput" type="text" value="" class="hasDatepicker" autocomplete="off">

<input id="birthday" name="birthday" type="text" value="" class="hasDatepicker" autocomplete="off">

<select id="rectif1zpzId" name="rectif1zpzId" onchange="rectif1zpzchange()">
     <option value="0" style="display: none;"></option> <option value="5" style="display: none;">3.6.2 при всех</option><option value="13" style="display: none;">3.6.3 при каждом</option> </select>
```

1 Выводит сообщение – Не пропускает

Необходимо выводить сообщение  при rectif1zpzId=13 и dateInput – birthday > 65. Т.е более 65лет – Не пускать 
Например dateInput=26.08.2019 – birthday=15.05.1922 около 97лет

**JS**

```
 else if($('#rectif1zpzId').val()== 13 && $('#dateInput').val() - $('#birthday').val() > 65
){
            $('.errorrep').append('<h3>Необходимо указать “При проведении проф.мероприятий детям и взрослым до 65 лет”</h3>');
            $('.errorrep').css({'display':'block'});
            $('#draggable').animate({
                scrollTop:  0
            });
            return false;
        }
```

2 Выводит сообщение “Подтвердите действие на странице..” Но пропускает при нажатии на ОК

Необходимо чтобы выходила сообщение “Подтвердите действие на странице …” при rectif1zpzId==5 и dateInput – birthday <18. Т.е. выводить сообщение но будет пропускать
Например dateInput=26.08.2019 – birthday=15.05.2003 около 16лет

**JS**

```
 else if($('#rectif1zpzId').val() == 5 && $('#dateInput').val() - $('#birthday').val() < 18){        
     strMessage = (typeof strMessage !== 'undefined') ? strMessage : 'Вы указали возраст до 18 лет. Продолжить?' ; 
     return !!confirm( strMessage );         
    }
```

Comment: В каком формате у тебя значение $('#dateInput').val()  и $('#birthday').val() ??

Comment: В БД DATE_INPUT - DATE а BIRTHDAY - VARCHAR2(255). И далее в проекте переведен на формат Даты, т.е. выбирается дата с календаря у обоих.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используй объект [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

```
Вместо $('#dateInput').val() можно использовать const now = new Date();
const birthday = new Date($('#birthday').val());
const fullAge = now.getFullYear() - birthday.getFullYear();
```

потом сравнивай fullAge < 18

Comment: const now = new Date(); это получается системная дата, Записал для dateInput так const now = new Date($('#dateInput').val()); не хочет работать

Comment: сделай console.log(($('#dateInput').val());

Comment: Как записать console.log(($('#dateInput').val()); полностью?

Comment: Что-то во втором JS пишу else if($('#rectif1zpzId').val()== 13 && fullAge < 18){  но он даже не реагирует - не выходит сообщение “Подтвердите действие на странице …”

Comment: просто в любом месте поставь  console.log(($('#dateInput').val()); и посмотри в консоли что выдает(F12 вызвать инструменты разработчика вкладка консоль)

Comment: С console.log(($('#dateInput').val()); помогло, а вот второй JS где выходит типа окна сообщения 'Вы указали возраст до 18 лет. Продолжить?'  Теперь он перебивает ранее созданный такой же.

Comment: ты спрашивал "как осуществить сложение и вычитание полей по условиям основываясь на Дату" я показал тебе что нужно делать, теперь смотри в консоли что с чем у тебя сравнивается проверь так все условия и поймешь где ошибка. или выложи на codepen(https://codepen.io/) там проще разобраться

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97918/discussion-between-lev-shportak-and-wq55).